# Problems creating custom style for SharePoint 2007 Enhanced Custom Query Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007

I'm pulling some additional columns through on my Enhanced CQWP in SharePoint 2007 and trying to apply a style too them from my custom ItemStyle.xsl. I want to drop my columns into a table, but every time I create the style in my XSL I get issues with the web part saying:

"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

The moment I remove my style it goes back to displaying results. I have additional styles I have already created which work perfectly fine, but it's when I try creating a table I get issues. This is my new style code:

```
<xsl:template name="jonstyle" match="Row[@Style='jonstyle']" mode="itemstyle">
<xsl:param name="CurPos" />
<xsl:param name="LastRow" />
<xsl:variable name="tableStart">
<xsl:if text="$CurPos = 1">
<![CDATA[ 
        <table> 
            <tr> 
            <td align="left"> 
            <b>Title</b> 
            </td> 
            <td align="left"> 
            <b>Company</b> 
            </td> 
            <td align="left"> 
            <b>Title</b> 
            </td> 
            </tr>]]>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="tableEnd">
                  <xsl:if test="$CurPos = $LastRow"> 
                  <![CDATA[</table>]]> 
                  </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tableStart" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="Project">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Project" />
                    </div>
                </td>               
                <td>
                    <div id="Description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
                    </div>
                </td>               
                <td>
                    <div id="Jons">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@jons" />
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tableEnd" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:template>
```

Note: I've made sure I'm passing in the required var's from my Main.xsl file (i.e. my CurPos and LastPos:

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate">
<xsl:param name="CurPosition" />
<xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Style='TableViewProjects'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
            <xsl:with-param name="CurPos" select="$CurPosition" />
            <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
```

I've also added my extra columns in CommonFieldViews, and they work correctly in other view styles.

I've tried a few different ways of producing the table, but all give me the same issue. Can anyone help me with this please?

Cheers!

Comment: Don't worry about this question, I've managed to solve it! Typo in my XSL!!